# Finding series expansion in parametric setting

Tags: series-expansion

Suppose $y=f(x;p_1,p_2,...)$ and $t=g(x;p_1,p_2,...)$ are given where $p_1,p_2,...$ are some parameters. We want to find a series expansion of $y$ in terms of $t$. Is there a direct command or publicly  available program for doing this?

For example:

```
y == Subscript[p, 1] x + Subscript[p, 2] x^2
t == Sin[x] + Subscript[p, 3] x^3
```

Comment: Could you please think of a small concrete example to use as a guide ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks for example $y=p_1 x+ p_2 x^2$ and $t=\sin(x)+p_3x^3$

Comment: I don't know under which conditions it can be done in general. In your specific example it might be possible to get t=t(y) as you can invert the first equation exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how sound this solution is, but you can substitute `x` in `f[x]` with the inverse series of `g[x]` and then take the serie

```
fS[y_, t_, x_, xo_, n_] := With[{s = InverseSeries[Series[t, {x, xo, n}]]}, Series[ y /. x ->  s, {x, xo, n}]]

fS[p1 x + p2 x^2, Sin[x] + p3 x^3, x, 0, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but could implicitly write all vars as functions of `t`, then take derivatives and solve for first few in `y` to form a Taylor series. For the given example it is as below.

```
exprs = {p1*x[t] + p2*x[t]^2 - y[t]
     Sin[x[t]] + p3*x[t]^3 - t};
dexprs = D[exprs, t];
d2exprs = D[dexprs, t];

augexprs = Join[exprs, dexprs, d2exprs] /. t -> 0;

(* Out[766]= {p1 x[0] + p2 x[0]^2 + p3 x[0]^3 - Sin[x[0]] y[0], -1 + 
  p1 Derivative[1][x][0] + 2 p2 x[0] Derivative[1][x][0] + 
  3 p3 x[0]^2 Derivative[1][x][0] - 
  Cos[x[0]] y[0] Derivative[1][x][0] - Sin[x[0]] Derivative[1][y][0], 
 2 p2 Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 6 p3 x[0] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
  Sin[x[0]] y[0] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 - 
  2 Cos[x[0]] Derivative[1][x][0] Derivative[1][y][0] + 
  p1 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] + 2 p2 x[0] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] + 
  3 p3 x[0]^2 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] - 
  Cos[x[0]] y[0] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] - 
  Sin[x[0]] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]} *)

In[768]:= 
y[0] + y'[0]*t + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]*t^2/2 /. 
 First[Solve[
   augexprs == 0, {y[0], 
    Derivative[1][y][0], (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]}]]

(* Out[768]= 
p1 Csc[x[0]] x[0] + p2 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 + p3 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^3 + 
 t (-Csc[x[0]] + p1 Csc[x[0]] Derivative[1][x][0] + 
    2 p2 Csc[x[0]] x[0] Derivative[1][x][0] - 
    p1 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0] Derivative[1][x][0] + 
    3 p3 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 Derivative[1][x][0] - 
    p2 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 Derivative[1][x][0] - 
    p3 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0]^3 Derivative[1][x][0]) + 
 1/2 t^2 (2 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] Derivative[1][x][0] + 
    2 p2 Csc[x[0]] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 - 
    2 p1 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    p1 Csc[x[0]] x[0] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    6 p3 Csc[x[0]] x[0] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 - 
    4 p2 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    2 p1 Cot[x[0]]^2 Csc[x[0]] x[0] Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    p2 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 Derivative[1][x][0]^2 - 
    6 p3 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    2 p2 Cot[x[0]]^2 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    p3 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^3 Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    2 p3 Cot[x[0]]^2 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^3 Derivative[1][x][0]^2 + 
    p1 Csc[x[0]] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] + 
    2 p2 Csc[x[0]] x[0] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] - 
    p1 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0] (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] + 
    3 p3 Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] - 
    p2 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0]^2 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] - 
    p3 Cot[x[0]] Csc[x[0]] x[0]^3 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]) *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve):

```
y /. First @ AsymptoticSolve[
    {
    y == Subscript[p, 1]x + Subscript[p, 2] x^2,
    t == Sin[x] + Subscript[p, 3] x^3
    },
    {{x,y}, {0,0}},
    {t, 0, 5}
] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{40} \left(120 p_1 p_3^2-40 p_1 p_3+3 p_1\right) t^5+\frac{1}{3} \left(p_2-6 p_2
>    p_3\right) t^4+\frac{1}{6} \left(p_1-6 p_1 p_3\right) t^3+p_2 t^2+p_1 t$

*Update*

While you don't have access to M12, you can use `CloudEvaluate`:

```
$Version
CloudEvaluate[
    y /. First @ AsymptoticSolve[
        {
        y == Subscript[p, 1]x + Subscript[p, 2] x^2,
        t == Sin[x] + Subscript[p, 3] x^3
        },
        {{x,y}, {0,0}},
        {t, 0, 5}
    ]
] //TeXForm
```

> "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 6, 2018)"
>
> $\frac{1}{40} \left(120 p_1 p_3^2-40 p_1 p_3+3 p_1\right) t^5+\frac{1}{3} \left(p_2-6 p_2
>    p_3\right) t^4+\frac{1}{6} \left(p_1-6 p_1 p_3\right) t^3+p_2 t^2+p_1 t$